# React NPM inefficient regular expression complexity in nth-check

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image]

I googled lot about this issue.
But could not find this issue belongs to which library?
How to fix it?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github Dependabot alert: Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71282206/github-dependabot-alert-inefficient-regular-expression-complexity-in-nth-check)

Comment: I think the real answer to this problem is to quit using CRA. It's barely maintained if at all, one commit in something like 7 months. There are other tools especially if you've just started a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"resolutions" :{
 "nth-check":"2.0.1"
}
```

Add it in Package.json  then run npm install

Comment: Could you add some explanation about why and how it solves the problem? And what possible implications come with it?

Comment: This can be dangerous, at there is not constraint binding it to (1) devDeps only (2) react-scripts. And just a guess: would also silently silence any further vulnerabilities found in the future.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known issue, and it should not affect your actual app as it's coming from react-scripts package.

Open package.json. You will find this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
```

Take react-scripts and move it to devDependencies (if you don't have it, create it):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
```

Then, ensure you `run npm audit --production` rather `than npm audit.`

You can read more from official sources:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174#issuecomment-979449264

Comment: didn't work for me. Keep getting the warning

Comment: I already have react-scripts under developer dependencies and yet get the warning.