# Why am I getting 6 high severity vulnerabilities on using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

> **This is what I have got!!**

```bash
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone> npx create-react-app ./
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Creating a new React app in C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone.

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

added 1392 packages in 11m

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

added 52 packages in 9s

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

removed 1 package, and audited 1444 packages in 6s

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Created git commit.

Success! Created netflix-clone at C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone
  npm start

Happy hacking!
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone>
```

This is what `npm audit` tells!

```bash
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone> npm audit
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone>
```

Here is what `npm audit fix` does!

```bash
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone> npm audit fix
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

up to date, audited 1444 packages in 6s

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
PS C:\My Files\Software Development\netflix-clone>
```

On running `npm audit fix --force`, i end up getting even more number of vulnerabilities!

Thank You!!

Comment: did you run `npm audit`? or `npm audit fix`?

Comment: As this is shell output please format your code block with: 
```shell  
(code)
```

Comment: @Ross Yes, I tried running "npm audit fix", it does not do anything. On running "npm audit fix --force", it comes with more number of errors.

Comment: move react-scripts to devDependencies, since that's what it is. Then npm audit and snyk don't care.

Comment: I haven't voted to close this question (yet), but I rather strongly sense that it's a duplicate
of [github Dependabot alert: Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71282206),
which unfortunately is a badly written "question".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Create React App was created by Dan Abramov. He's written an excellent article about the issues with npm audit in create-react-app. It's a good read and I learned a lot about packages, npm audit and create-react-app.

https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

**TL;DR**

You can ignore these security vulnerabilities.

Comment: should we just ignore them? I got 6 high severity vulnerabilities after updating my NPM and node. I'm using  npm: '8.19.2', and for node: '18.12.0',

Comment: how shitty is a library when "high severity vulnerabilities" are features and not bugs...

Comment: Just an aside for people experiencing issues with Create React App (CRA), please note that [CRA hasn't been updated in over a year](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) and it is [no longer recommended](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13072) by [react.dev](https://react.dev/).

I would heartily recommend people building new React projects to instead use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project), which has a similarly easy getting started command:
`npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react`