# Security Vulnerabilities After Installing some NPM Packages in ReactJS Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, css-frameworks, npm-vulnerabilities

So, I'm learning to create a react app that uses a CSS framework like materialize and bootstrap. I use 2 different versions of npm to create the react js app. The first one is npm 6 and the second one is npm 9

When I installed materialize or bootstrap using npm 6, there was only 1 security vulnerability appeared, but it was fixed after I ran **npm audit fix**

But when I use npm 9, 6 security vulnerabilities appeared. To fix that, I try to use **npm audit fix** and **npm audit fix --forces**, but there's nothing changed, security vulnerabilities still exist

Here how my terminals look like

[image]

Is it because the npm package doesn't suit npm 9? If that's the case, is there a way I can use npm 9 to create react app with materialize or bootstrap as a CSS framework?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71282206/github-dependabot-alert-inefficient-regular-expression-complexity-in-nth-check - check this answer regarding the nth-check security vulnerability.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

Comment: @jonrsharpe so is it ok for not giving attention to that alarm?

Answer (score 0):

i hit the same issue on MacBook (MacOS), slightly different from above is

1. after run npm audit fix --force, it should more alert than before
   83 vulnerabilities (14 low, 19 moderate, 44 high, 6 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

2. after above command again as suggested
   npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
   npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr
   npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini
   npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix minimatch@3.0.4 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimatch
   npm WARN audit fix minimatch@3.0.4 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix minimatch@3.0.4 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix minimatch@3.0.4 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix minimatch@3.0.4 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar
   npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
   npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
   npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
   npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
   npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
   npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 5.0.1, which is a SemVer major change.
   npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
   npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead

added 410 packages, removed 1182 packages, changed 321 packages, and audited 1399 packages in 57s

235 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

## npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
css-select  <=3.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
node_modules/svgo
@svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
@svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
node_modules/@svgr/webpack
react-scripts  >=2.1.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

---

as you observed, it is back to 6 high severity vulnerabilities

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34206329)